# Finding relationship details within tableau xml file

Tags: tableau-api

I have used two data sources in a tableau. First I loaded sample xlsx file provided by tableau **Sample - Superstore.xlsx** with table Orders. Then in the **Sheet->Data->New Data Source** I loaded one more xlsx file **Sales Target (US).xlsx**.Internally the relationship is mapped between these xlsx file tables If we see in **Data->Edit blend Relationships**.

I just wanted to find where these internal relationship details is stored in the xml structure retreived from .twb file obtained  on unzipping the .twbx tableau application if we load the datasource as I mentioned above

Comment: which retrieved xml file are you referring to?

Comment: @AnilGoyal on unzipping the .twbx a tableau application a .twb file is generated which stores the metadata informatiion of the application in xml format

Comment: Any answers will be helpfull please

Comment: What I can understand from above is that you first connected some datasets in tableau, joined them with some relationships and saved the packaged workbook.  Now from this .twbx file you want to retrieve the join information! (yet I am unable to understand the need). I am totally unaware of how the tableau application works in backend! lets wait for experts here to propose answer.  I'll also learn something new

Comment: After loading the datasets I did not add any relationships.Internally the relationships are detected based on similar fields.So I want to know where these internal relations mapping is shown in xml structure in .twb file

Comment: If you only want to see how Tableau has joined the two datasets, that part is easy to tell, but I am not aware as to how these relationships are stored in backend!

Comment: @AnilGoyal yaa I want to know where these informations are store in backend **.twb** xml structure