# relationship cardinality details not found in .twb xml in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to find the relationship cardinality details from the **.twb** file but not able to find it.

From the .twbx tableau application On unzipping it a .twb file is generated which contains the metadata about the application in xml format even though it has a **relationships** tag but no cardinality information is obtained in that.Where can I find them in the xml structure

Comment: Any solutions please

Comment: Is there any difference between this question and [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230480/finding-relationship-details-within-tableau-xml-file) one?

Comment: Yaa in this case we add new data source with **Add** option from Data Source tab .Here on extracting the .twbx the xml structure contains the relationship details but was not able to find cardinality details(like one-many or many to many)